# Pull out specific word from description, but not limit entire query to that result?

Tags: sql

I have a query where I am querying for a specific word in a ticket's short description, in this case WAP. So my current query looks like

```
Select * FROM table1 T
WHERE T.short_description Like '%WAP%'
```

The problem is that this entirely only shows rows if WAP is present in the short description, and I lose important grand totals. For example if I have 20 airlines but only 10 of those airlines have WAP its telling me I only have 10 total airlines which is not correct.

How can I rewrite this query to solve my issue, is this where sub queries come to play? I am a beginner at SQL.

To add additional context, I am looking to see how many total aircraft have had tickets created due to WAP issues. In this example if I get back 5 issues I want to be able to divide it by total airlines (but using Tableau not necessarily in the SQL statement) so 5/20 would give me what I want, however I am currently getting 5/10 (or the restricted set that the LIKE statement is limiting me to)

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your table, then we can consider better.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)